# rails 2.2 - polymorphic has_many without using has_polymorphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to set up some new classes and associations in a  Rails 2.2.2 app (please don't ask me to upgrade it).

The idea is that there is a Conversation class.  It can have many `participants`, which are a mix of User and Pupil records, and it can have many `owners`, which can be a mix of a variety of things, **including** User and Pupil records.  This is what I have so far:

```
#the :owner association can point to *anything*, including a Pupil or User record
class ConversationOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end

#the :participant association will point to either a Pupil or User record
class ConversationParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :participant, :polymorphic => true
end
  
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversation_ownerships
  has_many :owners, :through => :conversation_ownerships

  has_many :conversation_participants
  has_many :participants, :through => :conversation_participants
end
```

This currently isn't working:

```
Conversation.first.participants
=> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Conversation#participants' on the polymorphic object 'Participant#participant'.
```

Now, I know that the has_many_polymorphs plugin was designed to solve this very problem, but the problem with using *that* is that it automatically makes associations for each of the listed classes, and because User and Pupil are in both participants and owners, they would clash:

```
OWNER_CLASSES = [:ilps, :lessons, :digilearning_modules, :resources, :pupil_groups, :pupils, :users]
PARTICIPANT_CLASSES = [:pupils, :users, :contacts, :parent_carers]

has_many_polymorphs :participants, :from => PARTICIPANT_CLASSES, :through => :conversation_participants, :order => "conversation_participants.created_at"

has_many_polymorphs :owners, :from => OWNER_CLASSES, :through => :conversation_ownerships, :order => "conversation_ownerships.owner_type, conversation_ownerships.created_at"
```

With this, the first hmp makes a `.pupils` association which effectively means "participants that are Pupils", and the second hmp **also** makes a `.pupils` association which effectively means "*owners* that are Pupils".

I don't want these extra associations that has_many_polymorphs brings, which is why i thought I would roll my own associations.  But, I can't get past that `Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Conversation#participants' on the polymorphic object 'Participant#participant'.` error.

This feels like it should be possible - is it?